# How to request permissions in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been searching all over stackoverflow and the Xamarin forum, but all of the code I found never works. Most of the keywords give the error: "x does not exist in the current context" and I can't find a namespace or library that contains them. I'm new to Xamarin, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. [Example of code I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmSoF.png)

Comment: Hi, First please write your code instead of posting a screenshot, 2nd please also share you Manifest.xml

Comment: please read [ask] before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in the project , then rebuild and rebuild it.

For requesting permission , you could install the plugin **Plugin.Permissions** from nuget .

#### Usage

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<LocationPermission>();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            //Gunna need that location
        }

        status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<LocationPermission>();
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        //Query permission
    }
    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        //location denied
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Something went wrong
}
```

For more details about the plugin you could check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: I looked at the plugin and it doesn't seem that it supports READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Those are the permissions I need. Sorry I didn't specify, I thought it worked the same for all of them.

Comment: In the plugin it called `StoragePermission` .

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**

You do not have to add any extra plugins if you follow this, Below example shows how you handle a location permission

In your OnCreate method check for existing permissions:

```
 if (!(CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) &&
            CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)))
        {
            RequestLocationPermission();
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeLocationManager();
        }
        InitPageWidgets();
```

Where Check permission Granted is a method something like this:

```
 [Export]
    public bool CheckPermissionGranted(string Permissions)
    {
        // Check if the permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Permissions) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

And the Request permission code looks something like this:

```
  private void RequestLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
        {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }
        else
        {
            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Once you accept or reject this permission this method will get called:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions,
                     Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == RequestPermissionsRequestCode)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length <= 0)
            {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.Info(Tag, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            }
            else if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PermissionGranted)
            {
                // Permission was granted.
                Service.RequestLocationUpdates();
            }
            else
            {
                // Permission denied.
                SetButtonsState(false);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission Denied", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I am missing a namespace or something, (this is in MainActivity.cs) Manifest, InitializeLocationManager, InitPageWidgets, and ActivityCompat all throw the error: "x does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Yes because those are pseudo methods they do not exist they are just for you to understand what you need to do where the only namespace you need is `using Android.Support.V4.App;
`

Comment: I think the reason your answer doesn't have any upvotes, FreakyAli, is because it wasn't explained that well... you reference variables that aren't explained, don't explain what's going on, don't explain how generic X# is going to call exported platform-specific CheckPermissionsGranted, etc.

Comment: @ericfrazer Hey man thanks for your input will try to incorporate it in my future answers!